# When splitting files (e.g. html, images, css, js etc) accross different files, should HTML and CSS remain on the same domain

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, optimization

I'm thinking about how to split my content across different domains. I understand that it makes sense to put CSS at the top to ensure that page can render as soon as possible. Then, does it also make sense to keep CSS files on the same domain as the HTML so that those can download in parallel with the HTML with an additional DNS lookup not required for those files therefor not delaying rendering? Would this make a difference?

Something like:

html, css files:

```
www.example.org/index.html
www.example.org/style.css
.
.
.
```

images, js files:

```
staticfiles.example.org/home/js/script.js
staticfiles.example.org/home/images/header.jpg
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer's right in source code of this page or any big websites. You can put any static files to different domains include CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer depends a bit on what else you're doing -- as @Le Trong points out, you *can*, but that doesn't always mean it's a good idea.
There's a limit to how many connections to the same domain a browser will open in parallel, 8 is a number I seem to have in mind for this (but that may be outdated). Having resources on another domain name means you get another bunch of parallel connections, and static/dynamic seems like an obvious split to make anyway. This is more likely to be relevant for images, though -- a modern workflow combines and minifies your CSS and JS files anyway.

Personally, I wouldn't bother too much optimizing away DNS lookups -- the way DNS is organized, everybody along the way caches lookup results, and your DNS is usually pretty close net-topologically speaking, e.g. assigned by your local internet provider.